# How to echo a single value from database with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I just started PHP and was wondering how you would echo a single value result from a database query.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$query = "SELECT `userID` FROM `users` WHERE username='bill'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

echo $result;
```

I figured out that $result contains an mysqli object based on the errors I was receiving, but can't get it to actually print out, say, "10001."

Comment: This is like mysqli 101. 5 mins of reading would have got you the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it

```
$query = "SELECT `userID` FROM `users` WHERE username='bill'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row["userID"];
```

https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: Thank you! I actually spent quite a while on this...